# Apache with directory listing does only show some files and folders

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, permissions

Using linux ubuntu.

I have all my files in `/var/www/`.

apache conf `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`:

```
#add Directory listings  
<Directory /var/www/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
</Directory>
```

permissions in /var/www/Message:

```
drwxr-xr-x 14 www-data www-data 4096 Sep  8 09:07 .
drwxrwxr-x 26 www-data www-data 4096 Sep  8 09:03 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 www-data www-data 4096 Sep  8 09:07 ajax
drwxr-xr-x  2 www-data www-data 4096 Sep  8 09:07 css
drwxr-xr-x  2 www-data www-data 4096 Sep  8 09:07 images
drwxr-xr-x  3 www-data www-data 4096 Sep  8 09:07 inc
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data 1117 Sep  8 09:07 index.php
drwxr-xr-x  2 www-data www-data 4096 Sep  8 09:07 js
drwxr-xr-x  4 www-data www-data 4096 Sep  8 09:07 lib
drwxr-xr-x  2 www-data www-data 4096 Sep  8 09:07 messages
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data  518 Sep  8 09:07 profile.php
```

from localhost, localhost/Message/ I can list up the following directories.

```
[PARENTDIR] Parent Directory            -    
[DIR]   inc/        2014-09-08 09:07    -    
[ ]     index.php   2014-09-08 09:07    1.1K     
[DIR]   lib/        2014-09-08 09:07    -        
[DIR]   messages/   2014-09-08 09:07    -    
[ ]     profile.php 2014-09-08 09:07    518
```

For example I can not access or show files in images/jane.jpg using the browser.
any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I dont have the reason for the trouble but here is my **stupid fix**.

I made a new directory with mkdir. 
Then I created all the subfolders needed with another mkdir.

Then I started copying all files from one subfolder recursivly to the other subfolder. I changed rights and ownership and now it works on the new folder.

The **rights and ownership** are the **same** as the one in the **question**.

Comment: If we're collecting stupid solutions that work, I had `rsync`-moved my `www` contents to a new place but left my symlink pointing to the old place that just contained the empty directories. So after creating a new symbolic link mine worked :)